# SSRS- How can I retrieve previous balance in order di calculate the current balance (total + balance of previous day) Report cash flow with tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

In a cash flow Tablix Report the Balance must be calculated by adding the Current GranTotal Value + the Prevuois Balance value, I can't figure out how to get the previous day balance (the first day in the range the balance = GranTotal).
See Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFz8j.png)
I tried with the following expression:

=IIF(Previous(Sum(Fields!ImportoDivisa.Value), "DataPagamento")=0,Sum(Fields!ImportoDivisa.Value),Previous(Sum(Fields!ImportoDivisa.Value), "DataPagamento")+Sum(Fields!ImportoDivisa.Value))

But as a result I'm getting the GranTotal of Previous day instead of the Balance of the previous day.
Any suggestions.
Thanks
Hawa

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using the following expression in the Balance TextBox:

=RunningValue(Fields!ImportoDivisa.Value,SUM,Nothing)